# Setting property value in async method

Tags: .net, asynchronous, identity

I've been discovering source code of Microsoft's identity and I've met this code there.

```
    public virtual Task SetSecurityStampAsync(TUser user, string stamp, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();
        if (user == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("user");
        }
        user.SecurityStamp = stamp;
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
```

I can't understand what is the purpose of doing that. Really, why did the do that?
The method's body not even wrapped in a task. 
So can someone tell me what is going on here and does it really make sense?
Do I have to do the same thing?
Thanks a lot.

P.S.
Here is a [link](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) to the repository of source code

Comment: The link doesn't point to the source code, just the repository

Answer (score 1):

It's a virtual method, it should allow for overriding implementations to provide an async version of the method.

The current implementation only sets a property, but an overriding implementation might need to do something more complicated, eg. writing something to disk, which should be async.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I understand that, but does it make sense to create an async operation for setting a value into a property of an object?
There are a lot of things like this in Identity.
All the time its just disturbing a thread pool for doing such fast operations.

So does it useful? Thanks.

Comment: Another implementation may need to call an external service to validate/process/transform the stamp, store it in a database or cloud storeag etc. You didn't provide the link to the original code so it's hard to guess how it's used without searching the entire repository

Comment: The link is in my question. But here it again - https://github.com/aspnet/Identity
Please.

Answer (score 0):

The method *does* return a Task that wraps a value of `0`, created in `Task.FromResult(0)`. You don't provide the link to the specific method, but I suspect this is just a default implementation that doesn't need to do anything asynchronously.

I suspect other implementations can override this to execute complex logic when setting the security timestamp, logic that may involve calls to external services and thus require asynchronous processing.